# Triggering setVisibility property with javascript from WebView doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm so noob in Java environment most likely I miss some very important thing here, but anyway here's my code:

Here's the object I've created within XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_screen"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Here's javascript code that suppose to trigger the function:

```
function hideSplash() {
    Android.hideSplash();
}

$(window).load(function(){
    hideSplash();
});
```

This is the function that supposed to be triggered by javascript:

```
public void hideSplash() {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Splash! Remove!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    View splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);
    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
}
```

As you can see I've placed a Toast alert at the head of the function to check if something happens. What I get is jsut this "Splash! Remove!!!" message and the "splash" object refuses to change its visibility for some reason.
Someone Please help me to make it work ... I've tried evrything!

I guess my whole approach might be wrong. What I want is to hide the splash screen image when the WebView Content is fully loaded:

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got it ...
I've described the function in the parent class and then called it from the javascript class. Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public class JavaScriptInterface extends Activity {
        public void hideSplash() {
            hideSplashHandler();
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Some onCreate stuff */
    }

    public void hideSplashHandler() {
        ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);
        splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
    }

}
```

I don't know if this is correct, but it works like a charm ^_^